# Is it actually possible to solve $\frac{xy}{\ln(x^p)(x+y)^2}=c$ for $x$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to solve the following for $x$

$$\frac{xy}{\ln(x^p)(x+y)^2}=c$$

where $p\in[0,1]$ and all other variables are positive real numbers ?

---

Without the $\ln(x^p)$ in the denominator, the solution simply is

$$x=-\frac{-y+2cy+y\sqrt{-4c+1}}{2c},\:x=-\frac{-y+2cy-y\sqrt{-4c+1}}{2c}$$

But does $\ln(x^p)$ make a solution impossible?

Is it possible to solve it $p$ assumed values like $1,0.5$ etc.?

Comment: I am afraid that only numerical method could do it.

Comment: Ah, so only approximations?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici   This is a set in R^2. What does 'solve' mean in this context?

Comment: If you know mathematica (or any other software), the draw the surfaces $z= \dfrac{xy}{(x+y)^2}$, $z=cp\log x$ and then find their intersections. Otherwise, as far as I know there is no closed form solution involving elementary functions.

Comment: @Nil. Even with special functions, I don't think that we could do it. Your idea is good but, being almost blind, this would be very difficult for me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, the best you can do (without numerical method) is to express $y$ in terms of $x$:

$$
\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy} = \frac{1}{c\ln(x^p)}
$$
$$
\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} + 2 = \frac{1}{c\ln(x^p)}
$$

Let $z=\frac{y}{x}$, then

$$
z+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{c\ln(x^p)}-2
$$ 
$$
z=\frac{\frac{1}{c\ln(x^p)}-2\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{c^2\ln^2 x^p}-\frac{4}{c\ln(x^p)}}}{2}
$$ 
$$
y=\frac{x(1-2c\ln(x^p)\pm\sqrt{1-4c\ln(x^p)}\;)}{2c\ln(x^p)}
$$
or
$$
y=\frac{x(1-2cp\ln(x)\pm\sqrt{1-4cp\ln(x)}\;)}{2cp\ln(x)}
$$

BTW, this means that $x\le e^{\frac{1}{4cp}}$.

Comment: There are unbalanced parathesis or else sqrt 1 should be written simply 1.

Comment: William Elliot: Fixed.